# Laravel 5.1 with Set-Cookie

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with Laravel 5.1. When we added Set-Cookie: HttpOnly;Secure in our headers, we cannot proceed to our api anymore. We can't use the api of Laravel. I think this is already fixed in new version. But I want to fix this in Laravel 5.1
I don't know what to do to make it work.

Comment: Please post the error message, or all the symptoms you are encountering.  You have a very complicated system in front of you, and the only thing you said is "it doesn't work". If you were a doctor and a patient came to you and said "Doctor, my body doesn't work.  How can I make it work?", what would you say?

Comment: There are no error messages showing. It's just that we can't submit the data to the api. It will only redirect to it's page once we submit the form. We are not submitting the form using javascript - we are using laravel blade.

Comment: From the sounds of it, you need to understand the framework and how the code works a lot better.  When you use redirect, it sends a 302 http code to the browser along with a url to redirect to.  The browser then will request that page and load it.  All this happens behind the scenes so the user doesn't notice that it is happening.  You need to go into the code and use breakpoints to see what the values are at different points in your code.  With the information you have given, there isn't anything that we can do to help.

Comment: I did try to use breakpoints in my controller where my form should be redirected after submission and nothing happens. It just reload the whole page still. So it doesn't go through my controller. I also tried to show error message in my exception handler if I can catch something, but nothing happened also. I don't know how to catch it now because the behavior should be - from the form, after submitted it should redirect to the path I assigned in my form and go to the controller. Since there are no message showing in my controller, it doesn't go in the path in our form.

Comment: When I see in my network, I saw that the page I should be redirected to has a 302 Found status.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out now what's the problem. We are setting "Set-cookie: httponly; secure" header in server so the xsrf-token was removed. And I think it is the one causing why we cannot proceed in submitting the form. So I add the following code in my VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
protected function addCookieToResponse($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->setCookie(
        new Cookie('XSRF-TOKEN',
            $request->session()->token(),
            time() + 60 * 120,
            '/',
            null,
            config('session.secure'),
            true)
    );

    return $response;
}
```

The problem is still there, we cannot still proceed in form submission. I still receive 302 Found when we submitted the form.

These are the 2 Set-Cookie header now:

```
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=<token>; expires=Thu, 07-Feb-2019 07:38:41 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; secure; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie: laravel_session=<session>; expires=Thu, 07-Feb-2019 07:38:41 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

But why is it the we cannot still submit the form?